# Check if value from one data frame can be found in another data frame in R

Tags: r

I have two data.frames as follows:

```
a$id <- as.data.frame(c("1-23-2", "2-3-231-2", "122-121"))

b$id <- as.data.frame(c("1-23-2", "122-121", "12-1223-12", "1221-12"))
```

I want to check, if all values of a can be found in b.

I tried this:

```
if (a$id %in% b$id){a$test <- "yes"} else {a$test <- "no"}
```

Which gives a warning message and the wrong result unfortunately.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `ifelse`.

```
a$test <- ifelse(a$id %in% b$id, "yeah", "no")
a
#          id test
# 1    1-23-2 yeah
# 2 2-3-231-2   no
# 3   122-121 yeah
```

---

*Data*

```
a <- structure(list(id = structure(c(1L, 3L, 2L), .Label = c("1-23-2", 
"122-121", "2-3-231-2"), class = "factor")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-3L))

b <- structure(list(id = structure(c(1L, 3L, 2L, 4L), .Label = c("1-23-2", 
"12-1223-12", "122-121", "1221-12"), class = "factor")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-4L))
```

Comment: Thanks, this works. For learning purposes, could you explain why my version doesnt work?

Comment: @Valentin Yes, have you noticed the warning when running your code? It evaluates just the first element, because your code is not vectorized. You can make it work by looping over each `a$id`, try an `sapply`: `sapply(a$id, function(x) if (x %in% b$id) {a$test <- "yes"} else {a$test <- "no"})`.

Answer (score 0):

You may have several base R approaches to make it, e.g.,

```
a <- within(a,test <- ifelse(id %in% b$id,"yes","no"))
```

or

```
a <- within(a,test <- c("yes","no")[(!id%in% b$id) + 1])
```

or

```
a <- within(a,test <- c("yes","no")[is.na(match(id,b$id))+1])
```

such that

```
> a
         id test
1    1-23-2  yes
2 2-3-231-2   no
3   122-121  yes
```

**DATA**

```
a <- data.frame(id = c("1-23-2", "2-3-231-2", "122-121"))
b <- data.frame(id = c("1-23-2", "122-121", "12-1223-12", "1221-12"))
```